# Best way to download all historic Ethereum ERC721 transfers

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, geth, etherscan

I'd like to download all the transfer events of tokens under a given contract address.

I know etherscan provides an API endpoint for this, however it is limited to the latest 10,000 transfers (even if paginating). https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-erc721-token-transfer-events-by-address

Is there a third party who can provide this data, or is my only option to get it directly from a node (Infura, Geth, etc.)?

Thanks!

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Limited to 10k transfers per contract? I know opensea events api can filter by contract address + token id and you can do before and after timestamps. But I don't know how far back they go.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You need to insert your API key (API_KEY) and the wallet address you want to explore in the main function.
The output will be as CSV file named data.csv

```
from requests import get
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.max_columns = 60 ## 0 by default
pd.options.display.width = 10000 ## 80 by default
pd.options.display.max_rows = 3000


API_KEY = ""

'''
https://api.etherscan.io/api
   ?module=account
   &action=balance
   &address=0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae
   &tag=latest
   &apikey=YourApiKeyToken
'''
BASE_URL = "https://api.etherscan.io/api"
ETH_VALUE = 10 ** 18
def make_api_url(module, action, adress, **kwargs):
    url = f"{BASE_URL}?module={module}&action={action}&address={adress}&apikey={API_KEY}"

    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        url += f"&{key}={value}"

    return url


class Collector:
    def __init__(self, start_block):
        self.start_block = start_block

    def get_erc721_transactions(self, adress):
        '''
        https://api.etherscan.io/api
       ?module=account
       &action=tokennfttx
       &contractaddress=0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d
       &address=0x6975be450864c02b4613023c2152ee0743572325
       &page=1
       &offset=100
       &startblock=0
       &endblock=27025780
       &sort=asc
       &apikey=YourApiKeyToken
        '''

        get_transaction_url = make_api_url("account",
                                           "tokennfttx",
                                           adress,
                                           startblock=self.start_block,
                                           endblock=999999999999999999,
                                           sort='asc')
        response = get(get_transaction_url)
        data = response.json()
        temp_df = pd.json_normalize(data['result'], sep="_")
        temp_df['gasCost'] = temp_df.gasUsed.astype(float) * temp_df.gasPrice.astype(float)
        print(temp_df.tail())
        print(self.start_block)
        temp_df['type'] = 'erc721'
        return temp_df


    def aggrigate_data(self, address):
        data = pd.DataFrame()

        self.start_block = 0
        while True:
            df = self.get_erc721_transactions(address)
            if df.shape[0] == 0:
                print('There is no erc721 transactions')
                break
            if self.start_block == df.blockNumber.iloc[-1]:
                break
            data = pd.concat([data, df])
            self.start_block = df.blockNumber.iloc[-1]
        data.head()
        data.to_csv("data.csv")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    '''Insert the wallet address you want to check'''
    address = "0x4c8CFE078a5B989CeA4B330197246ceD82764c63"
    Collector(0).aggrigate_data(address)
```